# Flutter Staggered Grid View tiles and scrolls

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I got my staggered grid view working but only in expanded widget. The result is this:

[example GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkCfj.gif)

However, I would also want my banner to be scrolled down as I scroll my grid views. Also, would it be possible to show 3 tiles per row instead of just two?? I am trying to make it like a gallery view like the ones they did on unsplash or pexels stock image websites.

Here's my code so far.

```
body: Flex(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: deviceSize.width,
          height: 650,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'assets/Big Sur.jpg',
                width: deviceSize.width,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    """\n\n\nA decentralized photography platform\nfor the devoted communities.""",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'PhoBlock',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 80,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Center(
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Center(child: Text('$index')),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
              return StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1);
            },
            mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```